# How to Convert Base64 String into Png Image Mvc5 C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am Trying to Convert a Base64 encoded string to A Png Image, But the Code Shows Exception of Parameter is Not Valid on `Image.FromStream()`. After Debugging i cam up with this error on MemoryStream Object "**ReadTimeout = 'ms.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException**'" . I am stuck, Is there any Solution or Alternative to Convert String to Png in C#?

Here is My code

```
string code = "string";
var databytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(code);
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(databytes);
Byte[] Bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
//Stream bytes
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length);
//convert image

Image newImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
newImage.Save("~/Content/");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
Image image;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert Base64 string into png in this way:

```
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

    Image image;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        image.Save("~/Content/", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    }
```

Comment: I tried That , But As i mentioned Its is showing exception at Image.FromStream(ms) the Exception is ReadTimeout = 'ms.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Comment: I moved the _image.Save_ part inside the _using_ block and updated the answer. It can be fix your error.

Comment: I tried, But same Error {{"Parameter is not valid."} occurs at Image.FromStream(ms) line

Comment: Actually I am Converting a Partial View to String, And then i wan to Generate Png from That String

Comment: Did you tried to encode your string with UTF8? 
_var databytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code);_

Comment: I am facing the same issue. what is the solution to it?